# solve a partition misalignment?

Tags: partitioning

I have a new Dell XPS laptop which had Windows 7 installed in it. 
It also had a default extra partition for "Dell Utility".
I installed Ubuntu in it on an Extended Partition along with windows and specified the logical partitions myself (for /,/home and swap).
Now when I open Disk Utility , it shows this "Partition misaligned by 512 bytes" error for the Dell Utility partition and "Partition misaligned by 1024 bytes" for the entire Extended partition where Ubuntu is installed.
Deleting the extended partition and re-installing Ubuntu may solve the problem of misalignment in the extended partition. 
But how about the Dell Utility partition?

If I re-install Windows 7 Dell Utility wouldn't be a part of the re-install. So that may not solve it either.
How do I fix this?

Note: The extended partition I made contains an NTFS logical partition for holding data accessible by both OSes(basically a personal data partition).

**EDIT: I  deleted all my Ubuntu partitions and re-installed Ubuntu like before,this time making them partitions with GParted via LiveCD.**

**Now the only problem is that there is a misalignment in the *Dell Utility partition*. The other misalignment got fixed. Now how do I get rid of that issue?**

Answer (score 1):

Boot from a live CD and fix your partitions using `gparted`.

See [here](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html#mozTocId748422) the usage of `gparted`.

Comment: How do I fix it? I mean what should I do on GParted?

Comment: That was a really helpful article. I read the whole of it. But I couldn't find anything in it that explained how to fix misaligned partitions.

Comment: +1, it worked for by repartitioning the disk(i had enough free space)